# Bash echo prints gibberish if I trying to interpolate variable that is result of script call

Tags: bash

I found very disturbing appearance when tried to do arithmetic operation. I need to pass variable that is a result of script call in `bc`, to divide it on 2.

Looks like this:

```
durat=$(echo -n `ffprobe -v error -show_format $1 | awk -F= '/duration/{print $NF}'`)
echo "duration: ${durat}" # output: `duration: 54.334689`
echo "scale=1; ${durat} / 2" # output: ` / 2e=1; 54.334689` !!!!!
dur=54.334689 # if I substitute it to `dur='54.334689'` it still works
echo "scale=1; ${dur} / 2" # output: `scale=1; 54.334689 / 2`
```

Also I tried to strip newlines from `durat` by echo -n.

Can anyone explain why I get this `/ 2e=1; 54.334689` instead of expected `scale=1; 54.334689 / 2`?

Comment: I don't see `bc`. Can you show a minimal and verifiable example?

Comment: bc isn't an issue here, issue is an echo result that I need to feed to bc. Minimal example is a script that I posted. I hope full script wouldn't be unrelated to question: https://gist.github.com/Firfi/f3f37de39f4cc77cc986 (NOTE: didn't used bc in this version _yet_ so $(( ... )) won't work with float.  _it_ isn't an issue, issue is echo result. Feel free to interchange $(()) call to `middle=$( echo "scale=1; ${durat} / 2" | bc -l )`

Comment: _Also I tried to strip newlines from `durat` by echo -n._ - You don't need this, the newline is stripped automatically when you assign the value to `durat`.

Comment: Cool. It doesn't work without 'echo -n' applying too though. I just tried it after a problem in order to exclude possibilities of newline problems.

Comment: Works as expected for me: http://ideone.com/PdAkjJ -- look for invisible characters or other transcription errors. Nominating to close as unreproducible.

Comment: If the output from `ffprobe` has DOS line endings, that would explain the symptoms. Try with `ffprobe ... | tr -d '\015' | awk ...`

Comment: Hey @triplee, your solution with `tr -d '\015'` actually worked for me. However it seems to be an ffprobe issue, I would bet problem is more general, and I wouldn't ever find it without your answer. Maybe it is worth issue it as an answer to this SO question; what do you think?

Comment: This is a massive FAQ. See the [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info)  for pointers to some of the dozens, if not hundreds, of duplicates.

Comment: I vote for closing. Thanks.

Comment: If you check {{echo "duration: ${durat}" | od}} or {{echo "duration: ${durat}" | hexdump}} , you will see the EXTRA character(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction of your string is leaving a carriage return character in it, so that the content is:

```
scale=1; 54.334689<cr> / 2
```

When you output that string, you get:

```
scale=1; 54.334689<cr>
 / 2
```

where the second line overlays the first, resulting in what you *see:*

```
s/ 2e=1; 54.334689
```

So, since it's `durat` that is the problem here (being set to `54.334689<cr>` almost certainly by the `ffprobe` output, rather than to the correct `54.334689`), you simply have to ensure you strip off the invalid character. You can do that with something like:

```
durat=$(ffprobe -v error -show_format $1 | tr -d '\r' | awk -F= '/duration/{print $NF}')
```

---

You can confirm the problematic output simply be executing:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_format yourInputFile | grep duration | od -xcb
```

and looking in the output for the `\r` characters.